# error message when creating virtual machine for new cryptocurency wallet

Tags: dpkg

when i try to create a virtual machine (the command i use is sudo bin/make-base-vm -suite precise -arch amd64 -allow) and i get this:

Setting up console-setup (1.108ubuntu15.3) ...
Your console font configuration will be updated the next time your system
boots. If you want to update it now, run 'setupcon' from a virtual console.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu17) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-81-generic
Processing triggers for resolvconf (1.78ubuntu4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sudo
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
W: --force-yes is deprecated, use one of the options starting with --allow instead.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I've never used any kind of virtual machine and i don't know how or what they are. I'm following a video tutorial. (I had to cut out the non-errors, the article would be too long).

Comment: the model cryptocurrency is litecoin

Comment: also, from what i could understand, there are 2 different types of virtual machines? one built into ubuntu? i've never done this before.

Comment: Configuration file '/etc/sudoers'
 => Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 => Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
  What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
  Y or I: install the package maintainer's version
  N or O: keep your currently-installed version
  D: show the differences between the versions
  Z: start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** sudoers (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ? dpkg:error processing package sudo (--configure):
 end of file on stdin at conffile prompt(found this)